# Tests not hitting breakpoints in Docker + XDebug + VSCode setup

Tags: php, docker, apache, phpunit, xdebug

*Already spent good part of the night and a several hours today, going through dozens of articles, videos and whatnot, I haven't been able to make it work.*

This is a Laravel 10 application, where I'm trying to debug some tests. The application is running inside a Docker container. Here is what I have achieved:

1. The container is based on `php:8.2-apache` and is correctly running the app as well as XDEBUG.
   [image: List item]
   [image]
2. I'm copying XDEBUG settings through an INI file and they get applied correctly.
   [image]
3. The following lines are also from `phpinfo()`:

   ```
   IDE Key:                      VSCODE
   xdebug.client_host:         host.docker.internal
   xdebug.client_port:         9015
   xdebug.discover_client_host:    On
   xdebug.idekey:                VSCODE
   xdebug.start_with_request       yes
   ```
4. `launch.json` configuration for XDEBUG looks like this:

   ```
    {
    "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9015,
    "log": true,
    "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
    "externalConsole": false,
    "pathMappings": {
      "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/backend",
    },
    "ignore": [
      "**/vendor/**/*.php"
    ],
    "maxConnections": 100,
    "xdebugSettings": {
      "max_children": 99,
      "max_depth": 3,
    },
   ```

   },
5. The docker service configuration looks like this:

   ```
    apache-php-8.2:
        build:
          context: ./
          dockerfile: /Dockerfile
          args:
             xdebug_port: 9015
        image: apache
        environment:
          - "APACHE_LOG_DIR:/app"
          - XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
          - XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=VSCODE"
        ports:
          - "8443:443"
          - "8080:80"
        volumes:
          - ../back:/var/www/html      
        extra_hosts:
         - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
   ```
6. Finally if `phpunit.xml` has anything to do, here is how it looks:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php" colors="true">
       <testsuites>
           <testsuite name="Unit">
               <directory>tests/Unit</directory>
           </testsuite>
           <testsuite name="Feature">
               <directory>tests/Feature</directory>
           </testsuite>
       </testsuites>
       <source>
           <include>
               <directory>app</directory>
               <directory>tests</directory>
           </include>
       </source>
       <php>
           <ini name="xdebug.remote_enable" value="1"/>
           <ini name="xdebug.remote_autostart" value="1"/>

           <ini name="xdebug.mode" value="debug"/>
           <ini name="xdebug.start_with_request" value="yes"/>
           <ini name="xdebug.client_port" value="9015"/>
           <ini name="xdebug.client_host" value="host.docker.internal"/>

           <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
           <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
           <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
           <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
           <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
           <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
           <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>

           <env name="XDEBUG_CONFIG" value="idekey=VSCODE"/>
       </php>
   </phpunit>
   ```

Many of these settings I have accumulated during my research, so there might be some redundancy or overlap.

The funny thing is that my breakpoints get hit correctly when I browse through the application in the browser. It is only PHPUnit that doesn't seem to stop by them. The tests themselves run correctly and I do see `OK(1 test, 1 assertion)` message, without stopping on any of the breakpoints that I have set in those tests.

Can someone help and guide me with what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your very first screenshot (the top of the `phpinfo()` output) -- show the same but captured inside PHPUnit test. I do not know how it will be here in your Docker, but you can have different php.ini used by Apache and CLI (which is what PHPUnit uses). It's a common setup if you run your PHP directly on a Linux/Mac host OS. You need to ensure that you have it configured in the same way, that Xdebug is present and enabled for CLI.

Comment: P.S. Might be better to avoid having `"hostname": "0.0.0.0",` line. I'm not using VSCode, but have seen multiple questions/answers here on SO where that was causing issues with VSCode not seeing the Xdebug connection. P.P.S. You can also enable Xdebug logging and try to debug something where it works (web page) and not (CLI / PHPUnit) and then compare them -- does Xdebug even trying to connect in the later / what the difference in responses etc.

Comment: P.P.S. `xdebug.remote_enable` and `xdebug.remote_autostart` -- that's Xdebug v2 options, they do nothing in Xdebug v3 (well, Xdebug may be printing a warning into PHP's error log about using outdated config params)

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks a lot for taking time to answer. I have removed `hostname` and also tried to capture `php -i` on the command-line inside a shell attached to my docker container. They appear to have good xdebug configuration. About your last comment, I had added them as a safety measure, just in case phpunit or something else still use the old options (hope their presence doesn't do any harm). I still can't get it to hit breakpoints. About log output, I think my xdebug configuration write output to STDOUT. I do see some JSON being spit in ther terminal (some `setBreakPoint` options).

Comment: 1) Well, what can I say here then: Point your Xdebug log to a file, do those working and not working debug sessions (save files under different names so that each contains only 1 debug session) and share them here -- maybe we can see something from there. It could be a wrong path mapping issue for example, maybe it's your `"ignore":` section in VSCode launch.json etc. 2) *"hope their presence doesn't do any harm"* no harm. Except Xdebug nagging about it into PHP log.